# Lucene TokenFilter with EnglishAnalyzer for removing numbers in scientific articles

Tags: java, lucene, numbers, token

I am indexing scientific articles with Lucene. I am using the following configuration:

```
EnglishAnalyzer analyzer = new EnglishAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_43, EnglishAnalyzer.getDefaultStopSet());

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_43, analyzer);
```

That's good for words. But I would like to remove tokens like "0.99" or "3,14" but preserve text like "H2O" (and if it is possible also "n=3") in one token. I have tried the `SimpleAnalyzer` but is not what I want.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve what you want with custom, but simple `FilteringTokenFilter`, that will filter our all not needed tokens, for example by regexp. All you need to do, is to extend this class and implement `accept` method

```
protected boolean accept() throws IOException {
            String token = new String(termAtt.buffer(), 0 ,termAtt.length());
            if (token.matches("[0-9,.]+")) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

in this case, I'm filtering out all tokens that contains only digits and commas and dots (as possible delimiters)

```
        Tokenizer whitespaceTokenizer = new WhitespaceTokenizer(reader);
        TokenStream tokenStream = new StopFilter(whitespaceTokenizer, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);
        tokenStream = new ScientificFiltering(tokenStream);
```

For not filtering n=3 and other similar construction I would recommend to use `WhitespaceTokenizer`, to split tokens only on whitespace characters.

For a full example take a look [here](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene4/src/main/java/org/mystic/SkippingNumbersPreservingChemicals.java)

Comment: First of all thank you very much! Is working perfect! But I would like also tranform this "escape of carriers " into this "escape of carriers structures". I mean, to use EnglishAnalyzers. Is it possible? Thanks again!

Comment: EnglishAnalyzer is just a combination of LowerCaseFilter, PossesiveFilter, PorterStemming and probably something else, couldn't remember it by heart. So, you could just add what you need manually as well. EnglishAnalyzer will break n=3 into tokens, which you probably do not want